# Javascript dynamic dropdown options duplicate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dynamic dropdown lists namely Levels and Grades that can also do multi-select. “Grades” dropdown changes its values whenever I choose an option in “Levels” dropdown. If I select High School in “Levels” dropdown, then the “Grades” dropdown values will now be grades 7-10. Now, the problem is, if I select Kinder in “Levels” dropdown while High School has been previously selected, “Grades” dropdown values like Kinder and Prep duplicates. That’s not the only situation where duplicate is happening. The same thing happens when I deselect either one or both in “Levels” dropdown.

Here's my screenshot:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0FZQ.jpg)

Here are my codes:

* I am using select2 plugin for my dropdown lists

HTML - send_sms_non.blade.php

```
//Levels dropdown list
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control select2meAdd selectelement" required id="levels" name="levels[]" style="width:50%;">
 <option value="" selected disabled></option>
     @foreach ($data['stages'] as $stage)
       <option value="{{ $stage->id }}">{{ $stage->stage }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>

//Grades dropdown list
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control select2meAdd selectelement" required id="grades" name="grades[]" style="width:50%;">
</select>
```

PHP

```
public function getIndexNon()
    {
        if (!(require_school_access('ACCESS-SMS', 4))) {
            return redirect('/home/invalid-access');
        }

        $data['subscription'] = $this->subscription;
        $data['schoolfront'] = $this->schoolfront;        
        $data['accounts'] = SchoolAccount::where('school_id',$this->subscription->subscription->id)->get();
        $data['stages'] = SchoolStages::where('school_id',$this->subscription->subscription->id)->get();

        return view('school.send_sms_non', array('data' => $data));
    }

public function getAjaxDataGrades(Request $request)
    {
        $level_ids = explode(',', Input::get('level_ids'));

        // $selected_levels = array();
        // foreach ($level_ids as $level_id) {
        //     if ($level_id) {
        //         if (!in_array($level_id,$selected_levels)){
        //             $selected_levels[] = $level_id;
        //         }
        //     }
        // }

        $grades = SchoolStages::leftJoin('school_stage_levels','school_stage_levels.stage_id','=','school_stages.id')
        ->whereIn('school_stage_levels.stage_id',$level_ids)
        ->where('school_stages.school_id',$this->subscription->subscription->id)
        ->get();     

        return Response::json($grades);            
    }
```

JAVSCRIPT

```
$('.select2me').select2();

$('#levels').on('change',function(){
var level_ids = $(this).val();

   $.get('/sms/ajax-data-grades?level_ids='+level_ids, function(data){
        // $('#grades').empty();
        $('#grades').append('<option value="0" selected disabled>
        </option>');
        $.each(data, function(index, gradeObj){
           $('#grades').append('<option 
           value="'+gradeObj.id+'">'+gradeObj.level_code+'</option>');                      
       });
   });
});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .each function, you may use the following code to detect whether the incoming item existed in grades down drop box already.

```
var grades=$('#grades');
var allOptions=grades.children('option');
option = allOptions.find("[value='"++gradeObj.id+"']");
if (option.length==0)   //that mean does not exist
{    
    $('#grades').append('<option 
    value="'+gradeObj.id+'">'+gradeObj.level_code+'</option>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it.

Comment: Am I doing it right?
$.each(data, function(index, gradeObj){
                    var grades = $('#grades');
                    var allOptions = grades.children('option');
                    option = allOptions.find("[value='"+gradeObj.id+"']");
                    if(option.length==0){
                        $('#grades').append('<option value="'+gradeObj.id+'">'+gradeObj.level_code+'</option>');
                    }                      
                });

Comment: I am confused about where the problem lies if is it in my .each() really or ajax?

Comment: Should be both of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I am grateful.